# How to sort python dictionary by datetime key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
dt = {'2016-12-15 18:12:17': 1, '2016-12-15 17:40:39': 1, '2016-12-15 15:53:42': 1, '2016-12-15 15:51:41': 1, '2016-12-15 15:49:55': 1, '2016-12-15 15:49:54': 1, '2016-12-15 15:48:05': 1, '2016-12-15 15:27:38': 1, '2016-12-15 09:05:03': 1, '2016-12-15 08:43:45': 1, '2016-12-15 07:29:15': 1, '2016-12-15 05:56:58': 1, '2016-12-14 14:33:31': 1, '2016-12-14 14:33:30': 1, '2016-12-14 14:33:29': 1, '2016-12-14 14:33:28': 1, '2016-12-14 13:24:55': 1, '2016-12-14 13:15:51': 1, '2016-12-14 13:05:38': 1, '2016-12-14 12:58:47': 1}
```

I want to sort the dictionary on datetime key.

I tried :

```
dt = ordereddict.OrderedDict()
```

But it is not working please help.

Comment: an ordered dict maintains the insertion order it doesn't sort the keys by value, besides you have strings not datetimes. You'd have to sort the keys yourself and make a new ordered dict

Comment: Well, yes, `ordereddict.OrderedDict()` by itself won't do much. What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Errors? Is there any more code than this which you tried?

Comment: Get the keys by `dt.keys()` and sort them. Then access the values by the keys.

Comment: `ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the keys in `dt` into [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects, for instance, using [`dateutil.parser.parse`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse),

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
from collections import OrderedDict

new_d = OrderedDict(sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x: parse(x[0])))

print(new_d)
'''
OrderedDict([   ('2016-12-14 12:58:47', 1), 
                ('2016-12-14 13:05:38', 1), 
                ('2016-12-14 13:15:51', 1), 
                ('2016-12-14 13:24:55', 1), 
                ('2016-12-14 14:33:28', 1), ('2016-12-14 14:33:29', 1), ('2016-12-14 14:33:30', 1), ('2016-12-14 14:33:31', 1), ('2016-12-15 05:56:58', 1), ('2016-12-15 07:29:15', 1), ('2016-12-15 08:43:45', 1), ('2016-12-15 09:05:03', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:27:38', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:48:05', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:49:54', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:49:55', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:51:41', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:53:42', 1), ('2016-12-15 17:40:39', 1), ('2016-12-15 18:12:17', 1)])

'''
```

---

In your specific case, as pointed by @AndreaCorbellini, sorting strings directly works fine, i.e.

```
new_d = OrderedDict(sorted(dt.items()))
```

Comment: +1, just a remark: there's no need to conver to `datetime`: sorting strings written in that format will work just fine

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini, thx for pointing out this, I just added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works and doesn't need dateutil:

```
import datetime
sorted(dt.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(x[0]))
```

```
[('2016-12-15 18:12:17', 1), ('2016-12-15 17:40:39', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:53:42', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:51:41', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:49:55', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:49:54', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:48:05', 1), ('2016-12-15 15:27:38', 1), ('2016-12-15 09:05:03', 1), ('2016-12-15 08:43:45', 1), ('2016-12-15 07:29:15', 1), ('2016-12-15 05:56:58', 1), ('2016-12-14 14:33:31', 1), ('2016-12-14 14:33:30', 1), ...]
```

If you want the oldest date first, just provide `reverse=True` to `sorted`